# How to disconnect and connect socket.io after messge event triggered in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

here i am working on socket server and connecting it to the angular client every thing goes well the problem i am facing is when ever i call **getRequest** it should renders the get data from the **message** that i am getting

```
 getRequest() {
    this.sock.getData();
    this.sock.socket.on('message', (data) => {
      this.getresponseData = data;

    });
    this.sock.socket.on('disconnect',()=> {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
  }
```

here after this when i am calling the another method like **postRequest()** then the emitted message from the post request is triggering **message event** in get request()

**below is my post request**

```
 postRequest() {
    this.sock.postData(this.postData);
    this.sock.socket.on('message', (data) => {
      this.responseData = data;
    });
    this.sock.socket.on('disconnect',()=> {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
  }
```

in short when ever i call a postReuest the data emitted from mesasge is also going to message event in get request that should not happen.

On the Socket server side both the request i am using

**socket.send(data);**

Answer (score 0):

Socket inherits every method of [Emitter class](https://github.com/component/emitter/blob/1.3.0/index.js) which declares a [`once` method](https://github.com/component/emitter/blob/1.3.0/Readme.md#emitteronceevent-fn) for single shot listener.

The listener is deregistered after it is invoked the first time.

```js
 getRequest() {
    this.sock.getData();

    this.sock.socket.once('message', (data) => {
      this.getresponseData = data;
    });
    this.sock.socket.on('disconnect',()=> {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't want to subscribe message on both the methods.
2. if you want to get response according to the different methods you should register different keys. just like "message". And send the message according to key from server.

   this.sock.socket.on('getmessage', (data) => {
   this.responseData = data;
   });

   this.sock.socket.on('postmessage', (data) => {
   this.responseData = data;
   });
3. Another approach would be to have some identifier in api response.

   this.sock.socket.on('message', (data) => {
   if(data.m.type == 'get')
   this.responseData = data;
   else
   this.responsePostData = data;
   });

[Socket IO Ref](https://socket.io/docs/)

4. Another approach would be to use socket.ëmit

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is you are explicitly calling

```
this.sock.socket.on('message', (data) => {
      this.getresponseData = data;

    });
```

above each time. **This connects a single client multiple times which is not desired at all**.

This function must be used **singleton** for all the lifecycle of your app except you are calling  `socket.removeAllListeners('disconnect');` explicitly.

Use only once and if you want to get stream of a data after you do a http request. Your choice is wrong. You may wanna use classical http request there.